# Как мне работать с многопоточностью при парсинге?

Tags: c#

Не совсем понимаю работу многопоточности, в моем представлении многопоточность выглядит так.

Это человек который роет яму (**один поток**) и к нему ты добавляешь еще одного и типа они должны рыть два раза быстрее. Но тут встает вопрос о разделении площади работы на двоих, чтобы они друг-другу не мешали? **Так ли это?**

Чтобы перейти к более практичным вещам, я разрабатываю парсер, который работает по такой схеме.

У меня есть **xml** файл с ссылками на страницу товара, я читаю этот xml и затем сразу же перехожу по ссылке загружаю не достающую информацию по товару в базу.

Скорость работы меня не устраивает и я решил разобраться в многопоточности.

Обдумываю такую схему, я читаю весь **xml** и записываю его в базу, после того как я его полностью записал в базу, начинаю создавать потоки и каждому из них передавать записи, одному например четную запись из базы, другому не четную.

По идеи скорость должна возрасти в два раза и не возникнет ли у меня проблем если эти два потока решат одновременно произвести операцию записи в базу. И вообще является ли мой алгоритм правильным?

Будет приятно, если вы напишите на образных примерах и немного кода тоже не помешает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что нет смысла читать файл(ы) с одного *физического* накопителя в несколько потоков - это абсолютно не увеличит производительность (а может даже уменьшит). Так что, в вашем случае, скорее всего, узким местом будет именно чтение xml.

А вот дальнейшую обработку, уже после чтения с диска, вполне можно выполнять в отдельных потоках. Для этого удобно применять *конвейеры* ([pipelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx)).

Например, шаблон может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
var inputValues = new BlockingCollection<string>();

var readXml = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
        {
            while (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("nodeName"))
                inputValues.Add(xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
        }
    }
    finally { inputValues.CompleteAdding(); }
});

var processValues = Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var value in inputValues.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // обрабатываем value
    }
});

Task.WaitAll(readXml, processValues);
```

Такой способ также называют *производитель-потребитель* (producer-consumer). Один поток производит данные - другой(ие) их потребляет.

Использование [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx) автоматически обеспечивает много преимуществ, о которых можно почитать в справке.

При необходимости, количество стадий конвейера можно легко увеличивать:

```
var inputValues = new BlockingCollection<string>();
var processedValues = new BlockingCollection<string>();

var readXml = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
        {
            while (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("nodeName"))
                inputValues.Add(xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
        }
    }
    finally { inputValues.CompleteAdding(); }
});

var processValues = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var value in inputValues.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            // обрабатываем value
            var newValue = Process(value);
            processedValues.Add(newValue);
        }
    }
    finally { processedValues.CompleteAdding(); }
});

var writeToDB = Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var value in processedValues.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // записываем данные в БД
    }
});

Task.WaitAll(readXml, processValues, writeToDB);
```

Если один из потоков работает намного быстрее других и забивает память, то можно ограничить ёмкость его коллекции:

```
var inputValues = new BlockingCollection<string>(boundedCapacity: 50);
```

Таким образом, заполнив коллекцию до указанного значения, он будет ждать, пока другие потоки не выберут данные.

Обработку данных внутри каждой стадии конвейера можно дополнительно распараллелить, если это необходимо и вообще возможно:

```
foreach (var value in inputValues.GetConsumingEnumerable()
    .AsParallel() // распараллеливаем обработку
    .AsOrdered() // обеспечиваем правильный порядок, если нужно
    )
{
    // обрабатываем value
}
```

---

Можно ли в несколько потоков записывать данные в БД? Вероятно, на эту тему нужно задать отдельный вопрос, обязательно указав, какая именно СУБД используется и прочую информацию.

Многие СУБД имеют специальные возможности по массовому эскпорту и импорту данных. Например, [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/ms175937.aspx). Вероятно, их использование будет эффективней, чем ручное написание многопоточного кода.

Answer (score 3):

Парсить xml многопоточно - это сомнительная затея. Зачем-то использовать базу - на мой взгляд, тоже. По крайней мере, в вопросе я не увидел ничего, для чего была бы нужна БД.

А вот посылать запросы за недостающей информацией в отдельном потоке было бы вполне логично. Один поток парсит xml, и запрашивает недостающую информацию через другой. Также стоит обдумать, сколько одновременных соединений можно использовать.

Думаю, для этого подойдёт Parallel.For или можно самому написать что-нибудь подобное.

PS: Стоит обратить внимание на [эту статью](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2015/06/process-tasks-by-completion.html).