# C# AspNetCore. распараллеливание обработки данных. Как сделать оптимальнее

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, android-asynctask

Здравствуйте Стоит задача сделать пред обработку поступающих данных для Web сервиса на AspNetCore 2.2.

Сервис запускает до 100 параллельно работающих устройств, которые получают данные через POST запрос.
Что делает устройство с этими данными описывать не буду.

Появилась задача сделать пред обработку этих данных. 
Например, во входных данных,  есть поле "Name" типа String со значением "MyLongName" .
Инженеры задают правила, как преобразовать эту строку.

1. Обрезать строку если больше лимита
2. Вставить подстроки в нужные места
3. Сменить регистр
4. ...

Т.е. на обработку типа выстраивается конвейер из действий.

```
public class MiddleWareInData<TIn> : IDisposable
{
    public List<StringHandlerMiddleWare> StringHandlers { get; }
    public List<DateTimeHandlerMiddleWare> DateTimeHandlers { get; }

    private void HandleInvoke(IEnumerable<TIn> datas)
    {
        foreach (var data in datas)
        {
            //ОБРАБОТЧИКИ String
            Parallel.ForEach(StringHandlers, (stringHandler) =>
            {
                //Псевдо код обработки !!!
                var str = "Начальная строка";          //Найденное свойство в типе через рефлексию
                var res = stringHandler.Convert(str);  //Преобразование
                str = res;                             //перезаписали занчение свойства
            });

            //ОБРАБОТЧИКИ DateTime
            //foreach (var dateTimeHandler in DateTimeHandlers)
            //{

            //}
        }
    }
}


public class StringHandlerMiddleWare : BaseHandlerMiddleWare<string>
{

    public StringHandlerMiddleWare(StringHandlerMiddleWareOption option)
    {
        PropName = option.PropName;

        if (option.InseartStringConverterOption != null)
        {
            Converters.Add(new InseartStringConverter(option.InseartStringConverterOption));
        }
        if (option.LimitStringConverterOption != null)
        {
            Converters.Add(new LimitStringComverter(option.LimitStringConverterOption));
        }
        if (option.ReplaceEmptyStringConverterOption != null)
        {
            Converters.Add(new ReplaceEmptyStringConverter(option.ReplaceEmptyStringConverterOption));
        }
    }
}


public abstract class BaseHandlerMiddleWare<T>
{
    public string PropName { get; protected set; }
    protected readonly List<IConverterMiddleWare<T>> Converters = new List<IConverterMiddleWare<T>>();

    public virtual T Convert(T inProp)
    {
        var processedPrallel = Converters
            .AsParallel()
            .AsOrdered();

        foreach (var converter in processedPrallel)
        {
            inProp = converter.Convert(inProp);
        }
        return inProp;
    }
}
```

В классе MiddleWareInData данные поступают в метод HandleInvoke, в котором последовательно по 1 начинают обрабатываться.
Я решил распараллелить обработку.
Самое простое применить Parallel.ForEach и распараллелеить обработку по типам (параллельно обрабатываются все типы String для единицы данных)
Внутри обработки типа String, запускается конвейер обработки типа, который тоже можно запустить параллельно (С СОХРАНЕНИЕМ ПОРЯДКА ВЫЗОВОВ КОНВЕРТЕРОВ) с помощью PLINQ.
Еще можно параллельно запустить перебор самих данных для stringHandler также с помощью Parallel.ForEach.

Т.е. мы получим список входных данных которые начинают параллельно обрабатываться по 1.
Внутри обработчика этой единицы данных, все строковые типы обрабатываются параллельно.
Конвейер обработки строкового типа также параллелен (с сохранением порядка вызовов).

Думал над применением MapReduce, но Reduce (свертка) в конце обработки не нужна, в конце будет тот же список данных что и на входе, только с преобразованными данными.
Нормально ли так параллелить обработку или надо ограничивать кол-во потоков в ручную например для Parallel.ForEach.
Или может где-то использовать Task-и.

Возьму конкретный пример для анализа
Параллельно работающих устройств 100 штук.
Каждое устройство принимает список из 50 элементов.
Каждый элемент обрабатыватся 10 Обработчиками (10 типов String нужно поменять)
Конвейер обработки каждого элемента состоит из 5 этапов.

Comment: УТОЧНЮ ВОПРОС: НУЖНА ЛИ ТАКАЯ ГЛУБОКАЯ ВЛОЖЕННАЯ ПАРАЛЛЕЛЬНАЯ ОБРАБОТКА? ДАСТ ЛИ ОНА ПРОФИТ ИЛИ НАОБОРОТ ЗАМЕДЛИТ ВЫПОЛЕНИНИЕ

Comment: Если вам нужен конвейер с сохранением порядка конвертеров, то сам собой напрашивается [producer/consumer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/184217). Ещё ссылки: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/794380/184217), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585511/184217). [pipelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff963548(v=pandp.10))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понял, как вы собираетесь запускать параллельную обработку конвертеров с сохранением порядка. По сути, если сохраняется порядок самого действия, то это уже не параллельная обработка, а последовательная.

Я думаю, вам будет полезен вот такой пример:

допустим, есть вот такой делегат

```
delegate string Process(ref string s);
```

и я накидаю несколько функций для него

```
string AddStart(ref string s)
{
    return s = $"START {s}";
}

string AddEndt(ref string s)
{
    return s = $"{s} END";
}


string ToLower(ref string s)
{
    return s = s?.ToLower();
}
```

После сего можно собрать конвеер по обработке строки

```
Process addStart = AddStart;
Process addEndt = AddEndt;
Process toLower = ToLower;
var process = addStart + addEndt + toLower;
```

Конвеер будет работать, запуская обработчики последовательно, проверить его можно вот так

```
var str = "My AwEsOmE string!"; 
Console.WriteLine(process(ref str));
```

Вывод будет вот такой

```
start my awesome string! end
```

Даллее, для параллельной обработки нескольких строк, можно вызвать вот это

```
foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                    .Select(x => $"NUMBER IS {x}")
                    .AsParallel()
                    .Select(x=>process(ref x)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);                        
}
```

Результат

```
start number is 0 end
start number is 1 end
start number is 2 end
start number is 3 end
start number is 4 end
start number is 5 end
start number is 6 end
start number is 7 end
start number is 8 end
start number is 9 end
```

Но в этом случае строки обрабатываются параллельно и результат может быть в любом порядке. Например, строка `start number is 1 end` может быть обработана и появиться в результате раньше, чем строка `start number is 0 end`. Если вам надо сохранить порядок входящих строк на выходе, вы можете добавить `AsOrdered()`

```
foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                    .Select(x => $"NUMBER IS {x}")
                    .AsParallel()
                    .Select(x=>process(ref x))
                    .AsOrdered())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);                        
}
```

Вывод будет уопрядочен

```
start number is 0 end
start number is 1 end
start number is 2 end
start number is 3 end
start number is 4 end
start number is 5 end
start number is 6 end
start number is 7 end
start number is 8 end
start number is 9 end
```

Что же касается распараллеливания самого конвейера, как я сказал, раз вы можете запустить следующую операцию строго после того, как предыдущая закончилась, то у вас конвейер последовательный, а не параллельный, и вы не можете запускать конвертеры для одной и той же строки параллельно.

Также имейте ввиду, что добавление многопоточности не всегда ведет к ускорению работы. Например, если вы будете слать много мелких операций в потоки, то процессор будет только и делать, что переключаться между потоками, так как переключение между потоками - дорогая операция.

Ограничивать количество потоков вручную тоже стоит только если вы уверены в том, что делаете. Планировщик по умолчанию достаточно умен, чтобы в общем случае доверить ему эту работу.

Как итог, если у вас на входе набор строк, и строк очень много, я бы спокойно этот набор доверил параллелить PLINQ, и не выдумывал бы ничего. Параллелить шаги ковейера смысла нет. Мало того, если вы хотите скорости и у вас прямо много правил для конвертации и строки сами по себе большие, то наверное, в первую очередь надо глянуть в сторону оптимизации самих конвееров, так как любая правка строки создает новую строку и тратит на это время, пропорциональное длине строки. Я бы посоветовал глянуть в эту сторону, и, может, звюзать StringBuilder вместо строки, или просто массив символов. Но в любом случае, любая оптимизация должна быть взвешена, измерена и доказана, что она действительно работает в боевых условиях.

Comment: Спасибо! насчет StringBuildera думал уже. Принял решение каркас конвертеров собрать на строках потом конвертеры оптимизировать. Насчет AsOrdered() в обработке, да я тут ошибся выполнение действий строго последовательное, а AsOrdered() именно результаты действий в нужном порядке располагает.

Comment: Насчет паралелльной обработки строковых полей внутри типа я понял, так и хотел сделать, все поля можно обрабатывать параллельно. Но также, можно еще и уровнем выше параллельно обрабатывать все типы IEnumerable<TIn> datas. Внутри паралельной обработки еще 1 параллельная обработка, вот и возникает вопрос, когда следует остановится параллелить задачи, на каком уровне вложенности обработки. Может Просто запускать Бенчмарки и смотреть результаты?

Comment: запускать бенчмарки на реальных данных и на железе, максимально близкому к проду. К тому же, я бы не спешил всё прямо параллелить. У вас есть есть какой то верхний уровень? Например, вот это `IEnumerable<TIn> datas` начните параллелить, а внутри не добавляйте параллелизм. Всё равно у вас потоков будет одновременно немного, если у вас на верхнем уровне будет 1000+ элементов, то планировщик найдет как занять все доступные потоки и все ядра процессора, и тогда параллелить вруниренности смысла не будет, проц и так под 100% уйдет.

Comment: ну и, кстати, я бы сначала написал вообще без распарпллеливания, измерил как оно идет, и если оно и так шустро и с запасом работает, то нет резона это оптимизировать. Вот если у вас будуи просадки по скорости, тогда можно добавлять параллельную обработку. Просто хочу вас предостеречь от преждевременной оптимизации.

Comment: Спасибо!!!  BenchmarkDotNet уже добавляю для Юнит тестов. Проверю все варианты.

Comment: На здоровье. Удачи с параллелизмом :)